# Excel's stock datatype doesn't detect Canadian mutual funds properly. It's a hit or miss

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, finance, stock

The Stock data type in Excel is amazing, however, it's often a hit and miss when trying to use it with Canadian mutual funds or ETFs.

These were recognized just by entering their symbol name:

```
[CIG2359]   CI Alternative Diversified Opportunities Fund A
[FID231]    Fidelity Canadian Large Cap Fund Series B - FE
[MFC4768]   Mackenzie Unconstrained Fixed Income Fund SC - FE
[RBF270]    RBC Bond Fund Series A - NL
```

But with these, it didn't work!

```
[CIG11112]  CI Canadian Dividend Fund Class A
[MFC4732]   Mackenzie US Dividend Fund Series A - FE
[MMF4529]   Manulife Dividend Income Fund Advisor Ser - E3 FE
[SUN104]    Sun Life MFS International Value Fund A - FE
[TDB2581]   TD Tactical Monthly Income Fund Adv-ISC
```

I tried:

- Entering the ticker
- Entering the fund name
- Finding similar funds that Excel detects and changing them to match the new fund. This has been somewhat successful, but far from perfect.
- Entering multiple names found when Googling the ticker.

Any help?

Thanks!